# dateutil.parser.parse is parsing '0001' as 2001. How can i solve this to read it as 0001 only

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

date = '0001-01-01T00:00:00+02:00'
parsed_date = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
year = parsed_date.year
print(year)
>>> 2001
```

Desired Output: 0001

Any Idea???

Answer (score 5):

When calling `dateutil.parser.parse`, you can also specify a parameter "parseinfo" ([see here](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse)). This is an object which defines certain behaviour when parsing the date, including how the date is handled. It has a "[convertyear](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo.convertyear)" method.

By overriding that method, you can change the default behaviour (which is [documented here](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-19e5d3331806e55ec2ba1b9e39458784cc0a0004)) to achieve what you're trying to do. Here's a slightly changed version of your code using this object:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

class NoYearHandlingParserInfo(dateutil.parser.parserinfo):
     def convertyear(self, year):
         return int(year)

date = '0001-01-01T00:00:00+02:00'
parsed_date = dateutil.parser.parse(date, parserinfo=NoYearHandlingParserInfo())
year = parsed_date.year
print(year)
```

which gives the correct output of "1". If you really need the literal `0001`, you can pad that integer like so:

```
print('{:04d}'.format(year))
```